# Mercadopago: Web Tokenize y la clase Mercadopago de PHP no funcionan

Tags: php, mercadopago

como bien dice el titulo estoy siguiendo las instrucciones para implementar Mercadopago Web Tokenize en mi sitio, siguiendo esta documentación:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-tokenize-checkout/receiving-payment-by-card/#editor_1593118251

Como bien dice la misma, se inserta un código HTML el cual funciona perfecto, abre el modal y me permite ingresar los datos de la tarjeta de crédito, ese formulario hace un POST al script PHP de mi sitio desde donde yo debo realizar el cobro, en la documentación aclaran esto:

"No recibirás ni el transaction_amount ni el payer.email por cuestiones de seguridad."

Y luego te indica que para realizar el cobro "Solamente debes realizar un API call incluyendo los datos que recibiste del checkout" los cuales vienen por POST y son:

-token
-issuer_id
-installments
-payment_method_id

En mi codigo de PHP intento ejecutar el siguiente codigo para realizar el cobro:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");
//...
$payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();
//$payment->transaction_amount = 156;
$payment->token = $token;
$payment->description = "Incredible Cotton Clock";
$payment->installments = $installments;
$payment->payment_method_id = $payment_method_id;
$payment->issuer_id = $issuer_id;
/*$payment->payer = array(
"email" => "kitty@hotmail.com"
);*/
// Guarda y postea el pago
$payment->save();
//...
// Imprime el estado del pago
echo $payment->status;
```

Y aca está el problema, cuando intento ejecutar esto MercadoPago devuelve el error "transaction_amount can't be null", pero ese es un dato que a mi no me llega, si fuerzo un transaction_amount metiendo un input hidden en mi formulario con el amount e intento ejecutar me devuelve "bad request" (esto es porque falta el payer email), si fuerzo ademas un payer email de prueba, MercadoPago (todo siempre en modo sandbox) me dice que el cobro se realizó y devuelve "approved".

¿Cual es el codigo correcto que debo ejecutar si payer->email y transaction_amount son datos que no me van a llegar por razones de seguridad?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que completarlos tú. Los puedes enviar por post en un input hidden o guardarlos en una variable de sesión en algún paso anterior. Luego al recibirlos (si los enviaste por POST) los sanitizas  y los asignas. O los tomas de la sesión según sea el caso que hayas usado.

Ej. tomándolos de sesión:

```
$payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();
$payment->transaction_amount = **$_SESSION['importe']**;
$payment->token = $token;
$payment->description = "Producto XYZ";
$payment->installments = $installments;
$payment->payment_method_id = $payment_method_id;
$payment->issuer_id = $issuer_id;
$payment->payer = array(
"email" => **$_SESSION['email_cliente']**
);
// Guarda y postea el pago
$payment->save();
//...
```

Recuerda que debes abrir la sesión con `session_start()` al inicio del archivo php.